# Displaying data in Excel Pivot Tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I am working on a project and being able to use a pivot table would make life much easier. I need essentially for one column to become the column labels which is fine, however I would like to display values (in my case counts) going vertically down the page, rather than being inserted again along the horizontal?

Cheers for any help

Comment: Please clarify by providing a little sample data.

Comment: Table of Numbers

                      MG1     MG2     MG3     MG4     MG5   Total
Count of X        1                        2                        4          6

Which is what I currently have, what I want, when I add another value is:

                      MG1     MG2     MG3     MG4     MG5   Total
Count of X        1                        2                        4          6
Count of Y         2          4                         1                      7

Comment: Would be clearer if you edited the original post with this info.

Answer (score 0):

i *think* it might help to post the sample data in your post rather than a comment, it's a bit tricky to delimit from there. but i *think* this might be what you're asking.

if 1) you want a count of each column name as a row level pivot, you'll get only one valid cell for each row/column in the resulting pivot. the row context for the column value and the count ( distinct ) of the row will always match 1:1: example below:

**Data** *(col2 is the formula `=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,A2)` and shows the number of times `a`, `b`, or `c` appears in column A)* :

```
+------+------+--------+------+
| col1 | col2 |  col3  | col4 |
+------+------+--------+------+
| a    |    3 | data   |    1 |
| b    |    2 | text   |    1 |
| c    |    1 | number |    1 |
| a    |    3 | text   |    1 |
| a    |    3 | text   |    1 |
| b    |    2 | number |    1 |
+------+------+--------+------+
```

**Pivot** *(notice how `a` only shows data for 3, `b` for 2, and `c` for 1)* :

```
+-------------+---------------+---+---+-------------+
| Sum of col4 | Column Labels |   |   |             |
+-------------+---------------+---+---+-------------+
| Row Labels  | a             | b | c | Grand Total |
| 1           |               |   | 1 | 1           |
| 2           |               | 2 |   | 2           |
| 3           | 3             |   |   | 3           |
| Grand Total | 3             | 2 | 1 | 6           |
+-------------+---------------+---+---+-------------+
```

if however, 2) you are asking for each column with a corresponding "count of" label appended to it's name for the pivot table, Try adding a helper column in the source table `=a2&" - "&countifs(A:A,A2)` (for our example in column E / `col5` AND assuming the column A is desired pivot header). The new `col5` will show values of `a - 3`, `b - 2`, and `c - 3` (for our example). Make `col5` the pivoted column or row and do the rest of your pivoting with the added label of how many rows you are using.

result of revision below:
**Data** :

```
+------+------+--------+------+-------+
| col1 | col2 |  col3  | col4 | col5  |
+------+------+--------+------+-------+
| a    |    3 | data   |    1 | a - 3 |
| b    |    2 | text   |    1 | b - 2 |
| c    |    1 | number |    1 | c - 1 |
| a    |    3 | text   |    1 | a - 3 |
| a    |    3 | text   |    1 | a - 3 |
| b    |    2 | number |    1 | b - 2 |
+------+------+--------+------+-------+
```

**Pivot** :

```
+-------------+---------------+--------+------+-------------+
| Sum of col4 | Column Labels |        |      |             |
+-------------+---------------+--------+------+-------------+
| Row Labels  | data          | number | text | Grand Total |
| a - 3       | 1             |        | 2    | 3           |
| b - 2       |               | 1      | 1    | 2           |
| c - 1       |               | 1      |      | 1           |
| Grand Total | 1             | 2      | 3    | 6           |
+-------------+---------------+--------+------+-------------+
```

hope it helps.

Comment: table formatting help at http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html courtesy of @pekka